# Why is git command not found over SSH?

Tags: git, bash, ssh, git-clone

I'm trying to git clone to my website over SSH through Terminal on OSX 10.9. I've definitely installed git - when I simply run "git" in a new bash window, Terminal shows me the most commonly used git commands. However when I run it while using SSH on my website, it returns "-bash: git: command not found".

Any ideas?
Thanks (in advance)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of SSH is to run a command line on a different computer.

Installing git on your Mac will not cause it to be installed on the server hosting your website. If you want to use it on that computer, then you'll need to install it there too.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you know how I can install git on the server?

Comment: The same way you install more-or-less any other program on whatever operating system the server is running.

Comment: Ok.. I found my way around my original problem by just avoiding it altogether and it's now doing what I want. Thanks again for answering.

Comment: I am having the same issue but in my case i have logged in through ssh to my own mac (working on some module for my project).. my mac have GIT installed as am using the GIT properly since long time but throwing error through SSH.